# Using URL parameters in node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have no previous experience with node.  I'm playing with the Express project which comes with VS2019, trying to create master/detail pages with a MongoDB data source.  I have the following three routes in /routes/index.js

```
//this works
router.get('/articles', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('articles');
    collection.find({}, function (e, docs) {
        res.render('articles', {
            "articles": docs
        });
    });
});

//this doesn't work
router.get('/article/:id', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var Id = req.param.id;
    var collection = db.get('articles');
    collection.find({id:Id}, function (e, docs) {
        res.render('articles', {
            "articles": docs
        });
    });
});

//this works    
router.get('/article', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var Id = req.query.id;
    var collection = db.get('articles');
    collection.find({id:Id}, function (e, docs) {
        res.render('articles', {
            "articles": docs
        });
    });
});
```

The first route populates works fine and gives me a list of headlines with the url `http:localhost/articles`.  The third works fine with a url like `http:localhost/article?id=60` It's the second one which has me puzzled.  I use a url like `http:localhost/article/60`, I use `req.param.id` instead of `req.query.id` and it doesn't pull anything form the database.  I've looked at loads of questions on SO and elsewhere and I can't see what I'm missing.  I've tried deleting route 3 in case it's intefering with route 2 but it makes no difference. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It should be `req.params`, instead of `req.param`

Comment: I agree with @Yousaf You could have tried console logging `Id`, which probably would have come up as undefined or thrown an error before the log. Either way, you could have known about which line has the issue.

Comment: @Yousaf  I've tried that too.  It makes no difference

Comment: Log the ID to the console. Log every variable that you're not sure of. Check if `e` contains an error.

Comment: @John log `req.params.id` and make sure its value is what it should be. If that's the case, then your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Yousaf.  `console.log(req.params.id)` gave me what I was expecting, `console.log(req.params)` gave me `{ id:'60' }`.I then tried `var Id = parseInt(req.params.id);` and it worked.  If you want to turn your first and last comments into an answer I'll give you the win - you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this, everyone who said that I needed to use `req.params.id` rather than `req.param.id` was correct, but there was also an issue where I needed to my variable `Id` to be an integer rather than a string.  `parseInt(req.params.id)` solved it

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. It should be req.params.id instead of req.param.id

Comment: There was a bit more to it that. The solution was to use `parseInt(req.params.id)` - ie convert the value from a string to an integer. See the comments  Seems bizarre that this wasn't also necessary with req.query.id